# Load Document and create object inside script patch

Tags: ravendb

I have an event object with Payments collection. When event is cancelled I need to add those payments to the appropriate User object Refunds collection. Based on the documentation I came to the following schematic script:

```
_(this.Payments).forEach(function(payment) {
  var user = LoadDocument(payment.UserId);
  user.Refunds.push(new { EventId = this.Id, Payment = payment });                                    
}
```

There are two things in this schematic script that I didn't find how to do right in the documentation:
1. Load another document by Id (line 2)
2. Create new json-object (line 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LoadDocument() is correct, however the loaded document isn't automatically tracked by any Unit of Work when loaded within a Patch.

You have to tell Raven to update/store that document as well:

```
var user = LoadDocument(payment.UserId);
user.Refunds.push({ EventId = this.Id, Payment = payment }); 

PutDocument(user.UserId, user);
```

If you really want to do this from a patch, the above might work. However, this seems like a more domain specific operation and *might* be better to model the behaviour in your application code (i.e. raise an event and add the refunds to the user objects from code). Not 100% sure how Raven handles transactions within patches and so on...

Edit: For your second question: You don't need to use the 'new' keyword